# webapi invoked from Angular, but parameters are always received null

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to create a webApi method that accepts complex type, this method is invokable via AngularJs $http.post() but the values received are always received null. Tried almost all possible suggestions available on internet, nothing seems to work!! My code snippet below.

```
var config = {
        method: "POST",
        url: URLService.myBaseURL() + 'api/RequestApi/createNewRequest',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        data: $scope.dataToSubmit
    }

    $http(config)
    .then(function (success) {
        alert('A New request Created Successfully!!')
    }, function (error) {
        alert('There was an error while creating the request!!')
    })
```

C# webApi code

```
public class RequestApiController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public string createNewRequest([FromBody]Request dataSubmitted)
    {
      //BL here...
    }
}

public class Request {
  List<Activities> clearanceReqDetails { get; set; }
  .....
}
public class Activities{
  ....
}
```

Any help!!

Comment: What does $scope.dataToSubmit look like?  Along with the rest of the C# classes.

Comment: $scope.dataToSubmit, is the json populated from all ng-models when user clicks on Submit button. I have verified this json at http://jsonlint.com. This JSON is found to be valid. Sample json below
{
 "clearanceReqDetails": [{
  "id": 1,
  "VesselId": 1,
  "VesselName": "HAI GONG YOU 9",
  ....
 }],
 "StartDate": "05-Apr-2017",
 "EndDate": "05-Apr-2017",
 "requestor": "User",
 "team": "Charterers Clean",
 ....
}

Comment: @Pawan - have you verified that the json you're submitting matches the structure of the Request object?  Are you able to successfully call the api from the browser?

Comment: @jbrown, Yes. The JSON exactly matches the destination C# object. In fact, I have rearranged the object to match the order in which the JSON will be populated from AngularJS. But still the same issue. The api is also callable but the received data is always null.

Comment: Two things, firstly have you thought about running fiddler when you dev so you can see what you're sending and also create test posts. Second I would capitalise the first letter of your property names, ie use PascalCase in your C# code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved!! It was an issue with the access specifiers of the class properties, for serialization/deserialization to happen not only the class, but also class properties need to be have proper access specifiers. 
In my case, I resolved the issue by adding 'public' access specifier to properties of both the classes as below.

```
public class Request {
  **public** List<Activities> clearanceReqDetails { get; set; }
...
}
public class Activities{
  **public** ...
}
```